# What is fundamentally different between a logistic regression and a Logit Discrete Choice model?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, choice-modeling

I'm trying to understand the difference between the two. I know there is a background random utility theory in discrete choice modeling, but I can't pinpoint, in what I've read, the difference between the logit choice model (sometimes called a conditional logit choice model, to differentiate from a nested choice model).

Maybe it is something related to the likelihood equation, but I'd love some more technical clarification.

Comment: Possibly important is the link between the [Gumbel distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution#Link_to_logit_models_(logistic_regression)) and the logistic distribution and categorical distribution. The logit choice model seems to be derived using a different latent variable model (but ending up with the same as logistic regression).

Comment: What do you mean by "nested choice model"?

Comment: Like Alecos, I do neither see it clearly described which regression and which model you are exactly comparing.

Answer (score 3):

Logistic regression (using logit link) is a binary response model, with $P(y_i=1|x_i)=\hat\pi_i$ and $\hat\theta_i=x^T_i\hat\beta=logit(\hat\pi_i)$. Whether we want to predict $P(y_i=1|x_i)$ or $P(y_i=0|x_i)$, we use the same covariates for prediction. If the response has more than 2 levels, then the usual GLM model would be multinomial regression.

In a way, DCM is the far more complex version of logistic regression. For each choice $1,...,k$ we have a set of corresponding covariates, and naturally enough all other covariates **are not** used by this choice. That is, there is some kind of [hierarchical structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_choice#Defining_choice_probabilities) of the covariates. The set of variables belonging to person $i$ corresponding to alternative $j$ is denoted $z_{ij}$ and then we can write the *utility* $U_{ij}=z_{ij}^T\beta+\epsilon_{ij}$, and in general we expect person $i$ to choose alternative $j$ if $U_{ij}>U_{ik},\forall k\ne j$.

If we look at DCM for two alternatives, then it can be easily be written as logistic regression (see [here](https://www.scielo.br/j/sa/a/d83S6CxTKVHHpfWMZHt6ypb/?lang=en#)). If we have $K\ge3$ alternatives, then the probability of person $i$ choosing alternative $j$ is $P_{ij}=\frac{\exp(\beta z_{ij})}{\sum_{k=1}^K\exp(\beta z_{ik})}$. This is also sometimes called [multinomial logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression).

Therefore, logistic regression is the binary special case of the multinomial logit model.